# How to capture character without consuming it in boost::spirit::qi

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm using `boost::spirit::qi` to parse a "template" format that looks something like this:

```
/path/to/:somewhere:/nifty.json
```

where `:somewhere:` represents any string identified by the name `somewhere` (the name can be any series of characters between two `:` characters). I have a working parser for this, but I want to make one additional improvement.

I would like to know what character follows the `:somewhere:` placeholder (in this case a `/`). But the rest of my parser still needs to know about this `/` and consume it as part of the next section.

How can I "read" the `/` after `:somewhere:` without actually consuming it so that the rest of the parser will see it and consume it.

Comment: "I have a working parser for this" (unfortunately this margin is too small to contain it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sehe mentioned this can be done using the [lookahead parser operator &](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/and_predicate.html), but if you want to emit the character as well you'll also need [boost.phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/phoenix.html), [qi::locals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.qi.reference.parser_concepts.nonterminal.locals) and [qi::attr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/attr.html).

For example:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string input("foo:/bar");
    std::pair<char, std::string> output;

    std::string::const_iterator begin = input.begin(),
                                end = input.end();

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, qi::locals<char>, std::pair<char, std::string>()> duplicate =
          "foo"
       >> qi::omit[
             &(":" >> qi::char_[qi::_a = qi::_1])
          ]
       >> qi::attr(qi::_a)
       >> ":"
       >> *qi::char_;

    bool r = qi::parse(begin,
                       end,
                       duplicate,
                       output);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << r << " "
              << (begin == end) << " '"
              << output.first << "' \""
              << output.second << "\""
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
true true '/' "/bar"
```

Comment: Hrrrrmmmm? If you want to "emit" the character as well - that doesn't mean anything in the context of parsing, right? Neither the `&` or `!` parser operator consume any input. So, the obvious approach would be to 'handle' the _character_ you tested for in the following expression(s) - eg. `absolute_path`/`relative_path` in my sketchy sample. Zero need for phoenix, locals and what not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `absolulte_path`/`relative_path`. I do want to "capture" (i.e. "emit"?) the `/` and then keep parsing as if I never saw it. Is that what your example does? I was under the impression it didn't, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @3noch sure, what keeps the subsequent parsers from "capturing" the `/`? I linked to the documentation for the operators :)

Comment: @sehe I realize that your example allows the first parser to *test against* the `/`, but what I need is for the first parser to add the `/` to its attribute (i.e. "capture" it), and then "put it back" into the stream so that the next parser keeps chugging starting at `/` and onward.

Comment: I'll admit the word "emit" isn't the official term, but in my experience few people are familiar with the terms synthesised and inherited attributes. I meant to say that to synthesise the attribute the following needed to be done.

Comment: @VeXocide Thanks. I get it now. The word would be "expose as an attribute". I suppose this could be a way, thought I'd probably prefer putting the 'interpretation' side of parsing on a different _abstraction level_ (i.e. I'd use a ADT with further detail parsing or postprocess the exposed attribute tree)

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for

- [positive lookahead parser operator (`&`)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/and_predicate.html)
- [negative lookahead parser operator (`!`)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/not_predicate.html)

Example:

```
 myrule = lexeme [ *~char_(":") ] >> ":" >>
       (  (&lit('/') >> absolute_path)
        | (relative_path)
       )
```